# Inflating Google Maps in CardView in RecyclerView Android

Tags: android

I have cardView that gets inflated by a recyclerView.In this card view I have a google maps view. for weeks ive been trying to inflate the map but to know avail here is my RecyclerView XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

and here is my card view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5px">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_kasual_job_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Plumber"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textColor="#4a4dfc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_kasual_job_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur   adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_kasual_job_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location: Madaraka,Nairobi,Kenya"
            android:textColor="#0213fb"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

           <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/kasual_job_mapview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_kasual_job_date_time_posted"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="On: Friday 2016 July 14 8:05pm"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_kasual_job_user"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="By: Davison Mghanga Kimigho"
            android:textColor="#033dfc"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_kasual_job_inaproppriate"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Inapproppriate"
                android:background="#fefa01"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_kasual_job_apply"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Apply"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_inaproppriate"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_inaproppriate"
                android:background="#1af602" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_kasual_job_facebook"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_apply"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_apply"
                android:background="@mipmap/fb_icon"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_kasual_job_twitter"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_facebook"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_facebook"
                android:background="@mipmap/twitter_icon" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_kasual_job_google_plus"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_twitter"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_kasual_job_twitter"
                android:background="@mipmap/whatsapp_icon" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

and here is my Intent in the adapter

```
public class KasualJobAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<KasualJobAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private GoogleMap mMap;
protected LatLng mMapLocation;
private List<KasualJob> kasualjobList;
SupportMapFragment fragmentmanager;

public KasualJobAdapter(List<KasualJob> kasualjobList,SupportMapFragment fragmentmanager) {
    this.kasualjobList = kasualjobList;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView kasualjobtitle, kasualjobdescription, kasualjoblocation, kasualjobdateposted, kasualjobuser;
    public SupportMapFragment kasualjobmap;

    public MyViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);

        kasualjobtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_name);
        kasualjobdescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_description);
        kasualjoblocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_location);
        kasualjobdateposted = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_date_time_posted);
        kasualjobuser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_kasual_job_user);

        kasualjobmap = (SupportFragmentManager)fragmentmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.kasual_job_mapview);

        kasualjobmap.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;
                MapsInitializer.initialize(view.getContext());
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
                if (mMapLocation != null) {
                    updateMapContents();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setMapLocation(double lat, double lon) {
        mMapLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        if (mMap != null) {
            updateMapContents();
        }
    }

    protected void updateMapContents() {
        mMap.clear();
        // Update the mapView feature data and camera position.
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mMapLocation));
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mMapLocation, 10f);
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.kasual_job_card_view, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    KasualJob kasualJob=kasualjobList.get(position);
    holder.kasualjobtitle.setText(kasualJob.getKasualjobtypename());
    holder.kasualjobdescription.setText(kasualJob.getKasualjobdescription());
    holder.kasualjoblocation.setText("For Know its Utalii,Nairobi,Kenya");
    holder.setMapLocation(kasualJob.getKasualjoblatitude(), kasualJob.getJoblongitude());
    holder.kasualjobdateposted.setText("On " + kasualJob.getKasualjobdatetimeposted());
    holder.kasualjobuser.setText("By " + kasualJob.getUserfirstname()+ " "+ kasualJob.getUserlastname());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return kasualjobList.size();
}
```

}

And here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<KasualJob> KasualJobList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private KasualJobAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.user_feed_recycler_view);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    KasualJob a=new KasualJob("Davison",
            "Mghanga",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
            "Plumber",
            "Friday 12 July 2016 13:25:00",
            52.235474,
            21.004057);
    KasualJobList.add(a);
    KasualJob b=new KasualJob("Davison",
            "Mghanga",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
            "Plumber",
            "Friday 12 July 2016 13:25:00",
            52.235474,
            21.004057);
    KasualJobList.add(b);

    mAdapter = new KasualJobAdapter(KasualJobList, new FragmentManager() {
        @Override
        public FragmentTransaction beginTransaction() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean executePendingTransactions() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment findFragmentById(int id) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment findFragmentByTag(String tag) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void popBackStack() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean popBackStackImmediate() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void popBackStack(String name, int flags) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean popBackStackImmediate(String name, int flags) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void popBackStack(int id, int flags) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean popBackStackImmediate(int id, int flags) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getBackStackEntryCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public BackStackEntry getBackStackEntryAt(int index) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void addOnBackStackChangedListener(OnBackStackChangedListener listener) {

        }

        @Override
        public void removeOnBackStackChangedListener(OnBackStackChangedListener listener) {

        }

        @Override
        public void putFragment(Bundle bundle, String key, Fragment fragment) {

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getFragment(Bundle bundle, String key) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Fragment> getFragments() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment.SavedState saveFragmentInstanceState(Fragment f) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDestroyed() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void dump(String prefix, FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[] args) {

        }
    });
    final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

}

A little help can go a long way in this logic

Comment: I think you should use MapView instead of map fragment. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map

Answer (score 0):

The type of `fragmentmanager` should be `FragmentManager` **NOT** `SupportMapFragment`.

You should initialize the `FragmentManager` in your constructor.

```
public KasualJobAdapter(List<KasualJob> kasualjobList, FragmentManager fragmentmanager) {
    this.kasualjobList = kasualjobList;
    this.fragmentmanager = fragmentmanager;
}
```

Also change this:

`kasualjobmap = (SupportFragmentManager)fragmentmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.kasual_job_mapview);`

to this:

`kasualjobmap = (SupportMapFragment)fragmentmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.kasual_job_mapview);`

Comment: Their is no class such as SupportFragmentManager  acording to my IDE

Comment: Android Studio says,incovertible types cannot cast app Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Comment: Make sure you are importing android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: Thanks budddy,it worked,Thanks a million,only problem there is no emoji!! anyway looking at my solution below do you think the Maps will display, because I really want to solve problem for other users who might coma acroos the same

Comment: Hey Eric,I have edited my Question to include my Main Activity,it seems I am not sure on making an instance of a new FragmentManager,a little help

Comment: Don't make a new instance. I highly recommend you start reading about the basics of Android. You should do this: `mAdapter = new KasualJobAdapter(KasualJobList,getSupportFragmentManager());`

Comment: I Definitely need to read more on Google Anrdroid Maps, But While on that small change I got this error from logcat ----android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class fragment.Why?